# How to jump from one bash script to an other and do there some tasks?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, shell, scripting

My problem is:
I have myscript_1.sh and myscript_2.sh. When all tasks in myscript_1.sh are done the value of variable a should be send to myscript_2.sh. This variable a makes there some other calculations.

How I can do this ?

I read a lot, but I can't find out, how this is done. I really appreciate your answer. Thank you.

I read a lot about bash scripting and loops, but these informations belong exclusively inside a bash script.

I expect an example how this could be done.

Comment: You need to define what exactly you mean by **jumping**. If you want to replace your current process by a new one, you use the command `exec SCRIPTPATH`. If you want to invoke another program as a child process, you just call it, for  instance with `bash SCRIPTPATH`. Also, you have to think of how the invoked script is supposed to receive its input. There are several ways to do it.

Comment: _I expect an example how this could be done_ : We expect to see your attempts, how you tried it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass as positional parameters or export to the environment.

##### Positional

```
$ cat script1
#!/bin/sh
a=42
./script2 "$a"
```

```
$ cat script2
#!/bin/sh
a="$1"
echo "$a"
```

#### Environment variables

```
$ cat script1
#!/bin/sh
a=42
export a
./script2
```

```
$ cat script2
#!/bin/sh
echo "$a"
```